# Codeigniter - Trying to count articles view

Tags: codeigniter, view, count

Im working with codeigniter and  have a controller and 3 model functions to read, insert and update a column of table.
i want to get count of view from db and update it per each view!
but after the update an extra row added to table! with zero value for content_id.
please check once!

this is my controller:

```
  public function daily_report($id="")
  {

    $counter=$this->home_model->counter($id);
    if($counter)
    {
        $view=$this->home_model->counter($id)->row()->view;

        $views=$view+1;


        $this->home_model->update_counter($views,$id);
    }
    else{

        $views=1;

        $this->home_model->set_counter($views,$id);

    }
  }
```

This is the model functions:

```
  public function counter($id)
{
    $code=$id;
    $lang=$this->session->userdata('lang');
    $data = $this->db
        ->select('view')
        ->from('tbl_views')
        ->where("content_id",$code)
        ->where("language",$lang)
        ->get();

    if ($data->num_rows() > 0) {

        return $data;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
public function set_counter($views,$id)
{
    $data = array(

   'content_id' => $id ,
   'view' => $views,
   'language'=>$this->session->userdata('lang')
    );

   $this->db->insert('tbl_views', $data);
}

public function update_counter($views,$id)
{

$data = array(

            'view' => $views,

                );
    $this->db->where('content_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_views', $data);  
}
```

Comment: No, every thing is okey and no error! but for firt time when the database is empty the extra row appear and remain and update per each user view!

Comment: What extra row, can you show me the output?

Comment: yes, i cant put image in here! but please look this!http://s23.postimg.org/84t7ku0y3/table.jpg

Comment: If you can't put the image, how do you expect us to understand the question?

Comment: http://s23.postimg.org/84t7ku0y3/table.jpg

Comment: Okay, so you are trying to get 5 as the total viewcount?

Comment: no sir! the last row is unnecessary! its my problem!

Comment: You can to retrieve the value 4? Is that right?

Comment: yes its working and updating per each view! but i dont know why the last row created ?

Comment: Because it has a different ID, and a different count for a different ID.

Comment: but there is no content_id with zero value!

Comment: Quite, strange, need to see more code.

Comment: I'm hopelessly confused as to what you are saying here.